# Finding mode of an array in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the mode of an array in VBA.

Assume that there is a dynamic list of movie titles. A:A, and there is a just-as-long list B:B, which is a list of movie "types".

I am trying to find the top most repeated titles, of a certain type.

Note: A:A is a dynamic list, and I don't know it's length.

```
---------------------------------
-Finding Nemo  - Cartoon 
-Finding Nemo  - Cartoon
-Finding Nemo  - Cartoon
-Finding Nemo  - Cartoon
-Finding Nemo  - Cartoon
-Inception     - Action
-Inception     - Action
-Inception     - Action
-Dragon Ball   - Cartoon
-Dragon Ball   - Cartoon
-Dragon Ball   - Cartoon 
---------------------------------
```

Take this table for example, Finding Nemo is the most  occurred title. But now do I write a function to return that result?

I am assuming a function similar to this:

```
=movieMode(5)
```

Where 5 specifies the number of "top" results I want returned.

The problem here is I don't know how to do this when A:A is at dynamic length. And how to control how many results are to be returned. I should set a filter which only searches "cartoons" by default.

Please share some light on this.

**Update**

After some research, I found this formula.

```
=INDEX(A2:A177,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A2:A177,A2:A177)),COUNTIF(A2:A177,A2:A177),0))
```

This returns the most occurred title, under 2 conditions.

1. I use Ctrl+Shift+Enter (which seems to be loop through the range?)
2. There are no empty spaces within the range I specified.

I would need to improve this formula such that it takes E:E, where the `type` is Cartoon, and when A'x' is not empty. (this formula doesnt seem to work when the range is empty.

This is my first day using excel formula, and I am already coming across this. lol

**Further Update**

Considering the scenario I given above, I am expecting to use
=movieMode(2)

The results should be

```
----------------------------
-Finding Nemo    - 5 
-Dragon Ball     - 3
----------------------------
```

I am expecting the 'cartoon' filter to be set into the function by default. I never want action to appear at any point, nor for it to be a variable.

If however, I use

```
-movieMode(1)
```

The expected results is

```
-------------------
-Finding Nemo  - 5
-------------------
```

Comment: Does the argument value of 5 mean, get it me the movie which appears 5 times?

Comment: No. It means I want the top 5 most occurred movies. In the scenario I given, it wouldnt work since there's only 2 different cartoons.

Comment: Can you give example of sample output along with sample input to explain the test cases? does the search have to be limited to cartoons? If yes, where do you specify that in the function argument?

Comment: @shahkalpesh i've updated the question. Please refer, and thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @HeHui Since you are talking about arrays, does it mean you prefer a VBA solution?

Comment: VBA, excel formula, either one to make this work.

Comment: +1 for your question. It's interesting. I had this recurring questions in mind while writing the code. As per @Shahkalpesh questions to you, `1.` Do you want Top N by Category/ movie Genre? `2.` If two movies have same count like the results in my output, what do you want to do? Do you want to show just top 2 or all that has same value?

Comment: 1. No. Movie genre is merely a filter used to get rid of some irrelevant data. 2. If there are 2 movies of the same value, their order does not matter as long as they are listed. However, assuming that I am trying to get top 5 movies and there's more than 5 movies of the same "top N", I should get all the movies of that recurring occurence.

Comment: Well that to say if there are movies with same count, you will merely omit `top N` but show all that has same number... Come to think of it, `SQL` would be more robust..

Comment: Yes, but as I said in the beginning, I wasnt allowed to use SQL. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using Scripting object `Dictionary` and rather not very efficient `Range` processing at the end. However I utilized `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to keep some performance boost and to eliminate *eye-flickering* screen updates.....This is a `Sub` where as you may also use it as a function by giving a parameter for `Top N`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub getTopN()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim vArr As Variant, d As Object, aL As Object
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, lastRow As Long
Dim topN As Integer

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set ws = Sheets(1)
Set rng = ws.Range("A2")
topN = ws.Range("B2").Value '-- for testing it's 2
'-- get last used row dynamically
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'--since data starting with row 2
lastRow = lastRow - 1
vArr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng.Resize(lastRow).Value)

For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
    If Not d.Exists(RTrim(vArr(i))) Then
        j = 1
        d.Add RTrim(vArr(i)), j
    Else
        d.Item(RTrim(vArr(i))) = d.Item(RTrim(vArr(i))) + 1
    End If
Next i

'-- screen updating false
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'-- output items, keys in to sheet
Set rng = ws.Range("C2")
rng.Resize(UBound(d.keys) + 1) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
rng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(UBound(d.items) + 1) = Application.Transpose(d.items)

'-- sort this new range , top N
Set rng = rng.Resize(UBound(d.items) + 1, 2)
rng.Sort key1:=Range("D2"), order1:=xlDescending, header:=xlNo
'-- copy topN rows into a temp range
ws.Range("E2").Resize(topN, 2) = rng.Resize(topN, 2).Value
'-- clean up everything other than top N rows
rng.ClearContents
rng.Resize(topN, 2).Value = ws.Range("E2").Resize(topN, 2).Value
ws.Range("C1").Value = "Top N Movies"
ws.Range("E2").Resize(topN, 2).ClearContents
'-- release memory
Set d = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned, I literally just started learning VBA. lol. I'll try and understand what you're attempting, and I'll let you know whether it's i'm looking for.

Comment: what is `Sub`? I mean, how do I use it?

Comment: Google for theory and curiosity first. Then,you can question us  ;-)

Comment: no problem :) I noticed that you put both `Finding Nemo` and `Cartoon` into the same cell however. They actually belong to 2 different cells. Would that make the question easier?

Comment: If you don't take `genre` as a filtering criteria to count and list `top N` then, it doesn't matter if film name and genre in the same cell. But if it matters then by all means, split them into two cells.

Comment: I've managed to test this, and it works perfectly. :) 
In the end however, I realised that pivot table works almost exactly the same. I feel stupid for not realising that earlier lol.

Comment: I didn't give you a pivot, BECAUSE YOU MENTIONED THAT, YOU HAVE EXTRA SPACES/TRAILING SPACES IN THE same FILM NAMES.... So Pivot doesn't seem to work for that... Otherwise pivot would do.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [VBA function from cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/distinctvalues.aspx) to return an array with only the distinct values. Once you have that, you can implement the logic below (which is similar to the formula you already have) to generate your results. These are worksheet formulas but you should be able to accomplish the same thing in VBA. The [cpearson website](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx) is a good resource for VBA, by the way.

```
title genre       distinct  cpearsonVBA     count                tieBreak         rank            #_of_results   filter_array        result
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finding Nemo      Cartoon   Finding Nemo    =COUNTIFS(A:A,C:C)   =ROW()^-9+D:D    =RANK(E:E,E:E)   2             =IF(F:F<=$G$2,1,0)  =IF(H:H,C:C,"")
Finding Nemo      Cartoon   Inception       =COUNTIFS(A:A,C:C)   =ROW()^-9+D:D    =RANK(E:E,E:E)                 =IF(F:F<=$G$2,1,0)  =IF(H:H,C:C,"")
Finding Nemo      Cartoon   Dragon Ball     =COUNTIFS(A:A,C:C)   =ROW()^-9+D:D    =RANK(E:E,E:E)                 =IF(F:F<=$G$2,1,0)  =IF(H:H,C:C,"")
Finding Nemo      Cartoon              
Finding Nemo      Cartoon              
Inception         Action             
Inception         Action             
Inception         Action             
Dragon Ball       Cartoon              
Dragon Ball       Cartoon              
Dragon Ball       Cartoon
```

Comment: thx for attempting, but you're missing a very core question i was asking. The main issue is the dynamism. I do not know how many different types of titles. Hence it's not possible for me to use your solution, as it's fixated at 3 different titles only.

Comment: What I mean is, your method works when I only have `finding Nemo`, `inception` and `dragon ball`. If I add a forth `Lion King` in, I will have to readjust my template, to read the cpearsonVBA list you generated, which is exactly what i am trying to avoid.

Comment: I can see how my answer was confusing, but this should work. You could use the DistinctValues function from the link to create a VBA array and then go from there.

Comment: not that it's confusing, but this is not an answer I'm looking for. I am looking for a solution which will dynamically detect all the titles, and generate the final result I want. I don't want any process that needs manual clicking, or generating a second list in order to get my results. I'm sure your solution works, as there's lots of similar solutions out there that works along the line of yours.

Comment: Ahh... I was assuming that you already had the input list, and that the problem was getting the distinct values. If you are doing this in VBA, then you can select all the data in column a using 'Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 1)'